# Do the events in the Lego Batman movie take place in the same universe as The Lego Movie?

Tags: the-lego-movie, the-lego-batman-movie, lego-cinematic-universe

Do the events in both movies take place in the same universe? The rules for both movies are the same: "We're built on top of a table!", Batman refers to being a master builder.

**Are they in the same universe?**

Comment: They always could be, and they always might have been, or they're not... ATM. Dude, it's Legos. :) The current answer, answers: *according to the writers*. I'd more enjoy some on-screen evidence (but I don't think there was any - good writers know to not trap themselves).

Comment: @Mazura What universe, worth its weight, has never stepped on their own toes though?

Comment: I was planning to ask this question. Nice to see I'm not the only one wondering about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes and no.

The film's directors have openly acknowledged that there's a connection between the two films and that the goal is to build an interconnected "Lego Cinematic Universe".

At the same time they utterly reserve the right to have the events of this and subsequent films *not* reflect the events of the "*external universe*" that we saw at the end of The Lego Movie.

> **Q.** **The film’s ending doesn’t pull back into the human world like the first film did, but it still sort of winks at the macro idea that
> we’re watching a movie about physical toys on a table. Do you think
> that’s going to be a staple of LEGO movies?**
>
> **CHRIS MCKAY:** *Everyone says this, but for lack of a better phrase, **there’s a LEGO cinematic universe that we’re building that has a sci-fi premise, as
> far as the world that the movies are taking place in for the majority
> of the running time, and the other world that’s out there.** I think
> over the course of the movies, we’re building out the relationship
> between those. **There’s no mandate necessarily to do that, but we are
> very actively working to find all of the rules and develop that
> relationship between the real world and the LEGO world.** You’ll start
> to see it in what we’re doing with Ninjago and what what we’re doing
> in LEGO 2.*
>
> <sub><sup>[LEGO Batman director answers burning questions about that ending](http://ew.com/movies/2017/02/13/lego-batman-director-burning-questions-ending/)</sup></sub>

and

> **Miller:** *"The thing is about these movies is that each of them have
> their own tone and their own voice. We’re doing this Ninjago one with
> Charlie Bean, we’re working on the Batman one, and each one of them
> feels like its own movie, but **obviously they all exist in the universe
> that the Lego movie existed in**, and so finding that balance has been
> part of the trick."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Lord And Miller On The Lego Batman Movie](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/lord-miller-lego-batman-movie/)</sup></sub>

Comment: I see a real cat in Ninjago trailer.