# Where does The Lego Ninjago Movie fit in the LEGO timeline?

Tags: lego, lego-cinematic-universe, the-lego-movie, the-lego-ninjago-movie

Where does *The LEGO Ninjago Movie* take place within the LEGO timeline? Does it take place before or after *The LEGO Movie*? In the Ninjago movie, the Green Ninja seems to still be finding his footing and therefore isn't a Master Builder.

Comment: The scene in *The LEGO Movie* where Emmet falls into the abyss can briefly be seen on a screen in *The LEGO Batman Movie*.

Comment: Related: [Do the events in the Lego Batman movie take place in the same universe as The Lego Movie?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/164382/51226)

Comment: Batman does make a couple of references to Master Building in his own movie (he tells Puter to "Initialize Master Build music" before building the Scuttler, and he tells Robin he will teach him to "Master Build his way into" the Phantom Zone safe. Not sure if that means Batman is a Master Builder or if it's hyperbole (or perhaps just a turn of phrase to describe what he considers complex building) on his part.

Comment: I’ve removed the part asking about the Batman movie as it probably made the question a bit too broad and wasn’t addressed in the answers yet. A new question about the Batman movie was previously asked [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/206128/58193) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Lloyd’s old version I meant the version that appears in the Lego Ninjago television show before the Lego Ninjago movie and in 2011 before the Lego movie where we can see a Lego green ninja in it from the show

[image: green ninja in lego movie]
[image: green ninja in lego movie]

So the Ninjago movie probably comes after *The LEGO Movie* since it features Lloyd’s new version in the *The LEGO Ninjago Movie* as seen here

[image: Lego Lloyd in *The LEGO Ninjago Movie*]

and if that doesn't help in *The LEGO Ninjago Movie* there appears a double decker couch as seen here

[image: Double decker couch in *The LEGO Ninjago Movie*]

and seen in the movie several times thus it is after *The LEGO Movie* in timeline wise.

[image: double decker couch]

Comment: Note that you can [edit] your answers by clicking on the edit link underneath them instead of adding another answer.